# Getting the shortest list from a list of lists

Tags: prolog

I'm working on a project and I have a problem with a predicate that needs to get the shortest list of all the lists in a list of lists. Let's say we have the following list:

```
Listoflists = [[u,f,c,x,e], [a,v,c], [r,j,[m], [a,l,c,p]]
```

So what I want is a predicate **shortest/2** that when asked `shortest(Listoflists, A)` answers with `A = [m]`. The thing is that I can't use *maplist/3* because of restrictions of the project and that's why I am asking myself instead of using others' questions.
I've seen that *keysort/2* is useful in these cases, but for that to work I need a list with pairs *(list, listlength)* (or something similar, I'm not sure) and I don't know how to get that. I'm working in Ciao Prolog if it's of any help, and thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If library([aggregate](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)) is not forbidden, then an easy solution would be

```
shortest(L,S) :- aggregate(min(C,E),(member(E,L),length(E,C)),min(_,S)).
```

library(aggregate) is powerful, and worth to learn, but your question could be solved easily using setof/3. Wanna give it a try ? Let me know...

*edit*

Using the standard builtin setof/3, the code is similar, using member/2 to visit each list'element and get its length, that is then used to sort (in setof/3) or minimize (in aggregate/3).

```
shortest(L,S) :- setof((C,E),(member(E,L),length(E,C)),[(_,S)|_]).
```

This works for the specific case, but library(aggregate) is more general, so I preferred to show before...

Comment: So, if I wanted to use this library, how would I declare my module? Right now it is like this: `:- module(_,_,[classic,assertions,regtypes]).` but if I write `:- module(_,_,[aggregate,classic,assertions,regtypes]).` an existence error occurs. Sorry if it's too obvious but I'm a bit of a noob in Ciao Prolog. Thank you for your kind answer!

Comment: Which Prolog ? Most likey, it doesn't have library(aggregate)... I'll show how to use setof/3...

Comment: I don't know which prolog it is but it doesn't have aggregate neither apply. But your last piece of code works for me! So thank you very much for the effort :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by creating another predicate (I here called it `shorter`) and then using it in `shortest`:

```
shorter(_, [], []) :- !.
shorter([], _, []).
shorter([A | R1], [_ | R2], [A | R1]) :- shorter(R1, R2, R1), !.
shorter([_ | R1], [B | R2], [B | R2]) :- shorter(R1, R2, R2).

shortest([], []).
shortest([A], A) :- !.
shortest([A, B | R], X) :- shorter(A, B, T), shortest([T | R], X).
```

Answer (score 1):

We can take a generative approach,

```
%% L must be uninstantiated
shortest( LS, L ) :-
  length( L, _),      % length of L is N=0 or N+1
  member( L, LS).     % L is a member of LS
```

The first solution produced will be the (leftmost of the) shortest in the list `LS`. So add a cut `!` if you need it.

Comment: this is nice, but you should reorder the arguments as required by OP, otherwise is rather confusing

Comment: The goal ```shortest(S, [[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g], [h,i], [j], [k,l,m,n,o]]))``` does not get the shortest sublist, it only enumerate the elements of the given list in ascending order of length. Moreover, after the longer sublist is produced, the execution stops with stackoverflow error (since goal ```length(L,_)``` has infinite solutions for L uninstantiated, each time with a longer list).

Comment: @slago: true, but a correct version wrt OP' requirements is easily obtained: `shortest(LS,L) :- length(L,_),member(L,LS),!.`

Comment: @CapelliC ah, you're right, missed that! thanks.

Comment: For anyone wondering how this sorcery works, `length` produces "lists of increasing length if `List` is a partial list and `Length` is a variable". So `L` is first an arbitrary list of length 0, which is then checked to see if it a `member` of LS. If not, it backtracks and `L` becomes an arbitrary list of length 1, and so on. Ref: https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=length/2

Comment: This works great for me because I don't have a list available but another goal that I can use instead of member. How do I stop it at the shortest solution (I don't understand how or where to add the cut)?

Comment: @wensveen after `member`, before the `.`, like so: `member(L,LS), ! .`. `length(L,_)` enumerates `L`s in increasing length order, with all their elements uninstantiated. when `member` (or its replacement goal) fails, next `L`, one element longer, is generated, and `member` is tried again, with the new `L`. thus the first time that the call to `member` succeeds, `L` will be the shortest. the control will pass to the next goal after `member`. if that is the cut `!`, the execution will stop.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would do do you:

```
shortest( [A], A ). % lists of length 1 are easy
shortest( [A,B|C], S ) :-
    shortest( [B|C], D ) ,
    shorter( A, D, S ).

shorter( A , B, C ) :-
    length(A,La),
    length(B,Lb),
    (   La < Lb ->  C = A ; C = B ).
```

But it leaves choice points hanging, its computationally expensive (two list traversals on every call), and it pushes a lot of stuff on the call stack: given a long enough list and you'll get a stack overflow.

A little refactoring, though, and we can improve on this. The below leaves no open choice points, it only computes the length of each sublist once, and it's tail-recursive, and so doesn't grow the stack.

```
shortest( [A     ] , A ) .
shortest( [A,B|Cs] , S ) :-
    length(A,La),
    shortest( [B|Cs], La:A, S ).

shortest( []     , _:S  , S ).
shortest( [A|Bs] , Lc:C , S ) :-
    length(A,La),
    ( La < Lc ->  X = La:A ; X = Lc:C ),
    shortest(Bs,X,S).
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution is:

```
shortest([L], L).
shortest([L1,L2|R], S) :- min(L1, L2, L), shortest([L|R], S).

min(L1, L2, S) :- min(L1, L2, L1, L2, S).

min([], _, L1, _, L1).
min(_, [], _, L2, L2).
min([_|R1], [_|R2], L1, L2, S) :- min(R1, R2, L1, L2, S).
```

The advantages of this solution are:

- It avoids the need to use of the conditional construct `(IF -> THEN ; ELSE)` (or cut).
- It avoids the need to compare two lists more than once to get the list with minimum length (independently of the order of the arguments).
- It avoids the need to sort the lists by length.
- It avoids the need to use special libraries.
- It works nondeterministically, when there are several lists with minimum length.

Here are an example:

```
?- shortest([[a,b,c,d], [e,f,g], [h,i], [j], [k], [l,m,n,o]],S).
S = [j] ;
S = [k] ;
false.
```